# Meteor for Linux using Windows 10 Linux bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, meteor, windows-10

**Context:**
I've read Meteor is developed differently for Windows and Linux (as expected), and while it works on Windows, on Linux it has some features that allow faster building times (among other benefits).

Since those building times are becoming increasingly important as I invest more time on Meteor, I am considering trying Meteor for Linux and see if I can improve my productivity.

**Actual question:**
Can I install Meteor for Linux using the Windows 10 Linux Bash Shell and obtain the benefits of Meteor for Linux inside Windows?

Answer (score 2):

A little late to answer this, but I am running Windows 10 with the [WSL (Ubuntu)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and was able to install Meteor via

```
$ # this will take a few minutes
$ curl -sL https://install.meteor.com | bash -
```

When I run `meteor run` it hits an error along the lines of

> Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.

So my solution is to run an alternative Mongo database in the background

```
$ apt-get install mongodb-server
$ mongod  # assumes you've created /data/db and have ownership
$ export MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
$ meteor run
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. You can install a Virtual Machine using VMware that can run Ubuntu or similar. If you are not an expert in setting up vm's, this could take you some time.

A friend of mine uses Windows to develop meteor apps, and he hasn't complained of performance. He's definitely not envious of my Mac set up.

Before you go setting up another environment, I would try it and see if it's painful or not. Probably more the issue is how much RAM you have, anything less than 4GB, Meteor may struggle, so simply adding memory might help and save you a bunch of work

Answer (score -3):

NO need virtual machine!

You need to install "xming" on windows and run xming

> https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/

write in bash shell "DISPLAY=:0 [APPNAME]"

> DISPLAY=:0 firefox

or write

> export DISPLAY=:0
>
> firefox